# How to Plot output of DEigensystem?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to compute the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the operator $$L(y)=y''(x)+y'(x), \ \ \ \ 0<x<\pi$$
$$y(0)=0$$
$$y(\pi )=0$$
using the DEigensystem command and I am faced with two issues.

First I can't add the boundary values in DEigensystem, Mahtematica doesn't compute anything from the follwing code

```
eigen = DEigensystem[{Y''[x] + Y'[x], Y[0] == 0, Y[π] == 0},Y[x], {x, 0, π}, 6]
```

and if I remove the boundary values, I can't Plot the eigenfnctions, the following code doesn't work

```
eigen = DEigensystem[Y''[x] + Y'[x],Y[x], {x, 0, π}, 6]

Plot[Evaluate[eigen[[2]][[1]]], {x, 0, π}]
```

Am I missing something? How can I plot the eigenfunctions of $L$ using DEigensystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your system using DEigensystem, you should specify the boundary conditions with `DirichletCondition`

```
L[y_][x_] := Derivative[2][y][x] + Derivative[1][y][x]
{eigenvalues, eigenfunctions} = DEigensystem[{
    L[y][x],
    DirichletCondition[y[x] == 0, x == 0],
    DirichletCondition[y[x] == 0, x == \[Pi]]
    }, y[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 4];
```

The result is

```
eigenvalues == {-5/4, -17/4, -37/4, -65/4, -101/4, -145/4}
eigenfunctions == {Sin[x]/E^(x/2), (Cos[x]*Sin[x])/E^(x/2), 
    Sin[3*x]/E^(x/2), Sin[4*x]/E^(x/2), 
    Sin[5*x]/E^(x/2), Sin[6*x]/E^(x/2)}
```

Then you can `Plot[eigenfunctions, {x, 0, \[Pi]}]` to get
[image: eigenfunctions]